# Cakephp Sanitization

Tags: forms, cakephp, textarea, cakephp-2.1, sanitization

i'm using Sanitize::clean for posts comments , but it's replace New Line from textarea with \n

i need clean data but with orginal style and not convert NEW LINE to \n

thanks

Comment: why are you cleaning in the first place? if you are using h() in your view the content is secure. what if someone wants to post something that happens to contain <...>? LIKE IT JUST DID. he would be very upset if half his text is screwed up or missing just because the developer was overprotective or felt like it :)

Comment: thanks a lot mark , you say we dont need any clearing incoming data from the form and just do htmlspecialchars() in our view ? then how we protected from SQL INJECTION and XSS or ... , thanks

Comment: i just told you. if you use h() there is nothing else you need to worry about. that's the power of a framework. that is if you use the wrapper methods like save() and not manual queries like query() or unescaped updateAll() etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your variable:

`nl2br(h($var))`

[nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string while [h](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/function-h.html) is CakePHP's shortcut for PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function.

You should not need to do more than `nl2br(h($var))` on your data.